# Group tableview by JSON array

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I am using swiftyJson to get some data, all is good and I get an array like this ("horario_emp"):

```
[
  {
    "dia" : 1,
    "itinerario" : 0,
    "id_horarios" : 13,
    "jornada" : "05:00:00 - 12:30:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  },
  {
    "dia" : 1,
    "itinerario" : 1,
    "id_horarios" : 11,
    "jornada" : "12:00:00 - 19:00:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  },
  {
    "dia" : 2,
    "itinerario" : 0,
    "id_horarios" : 14,
    "jornada" : "05:00:00 - 12:30:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  },
  {
    "dia" : 2,
    "itinerario" : 1,
    "id_horarios" : 15,
    "jornada" : "12:00:00 - 19:00:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  },
  {
    "dia" : 4,
    "itinerario" : 0,
    "id_horarios" : 10,
    "jornada" : "05:00:00 - 12:30:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  },
  {
    "dia" : 4,
    "itinerario" : 1,
    "id_horarios" : 12,
    "jornada" : "12:00:00 - 19:00:00",
    "id_empresa" : 1
  }
]
```

I wan to know How can I to group that array by "dia"? because I want to show that data into a tableviewcell like this:

dia 1
jornada 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00

dia 2
jornada 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00

dia 4
jornada 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00

this is my code:

```
class Horarios: NSObject{
    var dia: Int?
    var jornada: [String]?
}
```

my controller:

```
let horarios = Horarios()
var obj_horarios: [Horarios] = []
let res = JSON(data)
let status = res["status"].boolValue
if(status){
   let info_empresa = res["data"]["empresas"]
   for(_, sub_res):(String, JSON) in info_empresa{
      let horario_emp = sub_res["horario"]
      let allKeys = Set<String>(horario_emp.filter({!($0["dia"].string?.isEmpty)!}).map{$0["dia"].stringValue})
                for key in allKeys {
                    var horarios = Horarios()
                    obj_horarios = horario_emp.filter({
                        $0["dia"].string ?? "" == key
                    }).map({ (json) -> Horarios in
                        horarios.dia = json["dia"].intValue
                        horarios.jornada.append(json["jornada"].stringValue)
                        return horarios
                    })
                }
   }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I get this error Value of tuple type 'JSON.Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') has no member 'subscript' in the line let allKeys....
How can I group that?

Comment: create a Dictionary and add your key as dia and in the value put an array of  a model type for all the remaining data, then you can cycle over your array and if your dictionary for one dia is nil create a new array and add the first value if there is an array then add the new model to the existing array

Comment: How he will show that dictionary in tableview

Comment: @RahulDasgupta with sections and rows, each key is a section and each value in the dictionary value which is an (array) is a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't include using SwiftyJSON, instead it uses the native JSON parsing in Swift 4 and the `Codable` protocol. I'm sure using SwiftyJSON is great but the new native handling of JSON makes this task fairly simple:

```
// jsonText is a String that contains the JSON text
let jsonText = "" // fill in the appropriate text

import Foundation

// the struct to decode into (called Foo for lack of a better name)
struct Foo : Codable {
  let dia: Int
  let itinerario: Int
  let id_horarios: Int
  let jornada: String
  let id_empresa: Int
}

struct Horarios {
  let dia: Int
  let jornada: [String]
}

// push it into a Data and decode it
if let data = jsonText.data(using: .utf8),
  let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Foo].self, from: data) {

  let obj_horarios =
    // group the Foo objects by the `dia` property as keys,
    Dictionary(grouping: decoded, by: { $0.dia })
      // convert the Foo objects into an array of `Horarios` structs
      .map { Horarios(dia: $0.0, jornada: $0.1.map { $0.jornada }) }
      // sort them by `dia`
      .sorted { $0.dia < $1.dia }

  print(obj_horarios)
  // result:
  // [Horarios(dia: 1, jornada: ["05:00:00 - 12:30:00", "12:00:00 - 19:00:00"]),
  //  Horarios(dia: 2, jornada: ["05:00:00 - 12:30:00", "12:00:00 - 19:00:00"]),
  //  Horarios(dia: 4, jornada: ["05:00:00 - 12:30:00", "12:00:00 - 19:00:00"])]
}
```

Also, if all you care about are the keys `dia` and `jornada` then you can simplify the `Foo` `struct` to just contain those properties:

```
struct Foo : Codable {
  let dia: Int
  let jornada: String
}
```

Any additional keys in the JSON will be ignored during the decoding.

Comment: Excelent answer, my friend how can I loop the grouped because I want to add the value of dia to object and the jornada to object (all to my object horarios)

Comment: I changed the result from a `[Int:String]` to a `[Horarios]` by using the method `map` instead of the method `mapValues`, and by creating `Horarios` objects instead of just pulling out each `jornada` property as a `String`

Comment: Thanks my friend your answer is excellent. My last question how can I order     the dictionary by dia?

Comment: A `Dictionary` is an unordered collection. Do you want to order an `Array` instead? What does the `Array` contain?

Comment: I want order by dia 1 2 3 etc... actually it returns 3214

Comment: You mean the `Horarios` objects in the `Array`? You want them sorted by their `dia` property?

Comment: I added a sort to the code, now the array will be sorted by the `dia` property,

Answer (score 0):

```
    Define class 

    class Horaios {
        var dia:Int?
        var itinerario:Int?
        var id_horarios:Int?
        var jornada:String?
        var id_empresa:Int?
    }

    implement Sequence extension


    public extension Sequence {
        func categorise<U : Hashable>(_ key: (Iterator.Element) -> U) -> [U:[Iterator.Element]] {
            var dict: [U:[Iterator.Element]] = [:]
            for el in self {
                let key = key(el)
                if case nil = dict[key]?.append(el) { dict[key] = [el] }
            }
            return dict
        }
    }

Call Below method and Output will be like this

dia 1 jordano 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00
dia 2 jordano 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00
dia 4 jordano 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00

    func parseJSON(jsonString:String) {
    let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        //let groupedItems:[Int:[Horaios]?]?

        do {

            if let data = jsonData {
                let parsedJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves)

                if let arr = parsedJSON as? [Any] {
                    var items = [Horaios]()
                    for item in arr {
                        if let dict = item as? [String:Any?] {
                            let obj = Horaios()
                            obj.dia = dict["dia"] as? Int
                            obj.itinerario = dict["itinerario"] as? Int
                            obj.id_horarios = dict["id_horarios"] as? Int
                            obj.jornada = dict["jornada"] as? String
                            obj.id_empresa = dict["id_empresa"] as? Int
                            items.append(obj)
                        }
                    }

                    items.sort(by: { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
                        if let x = obj1.dia, let y = obj2.dia {
                            return x < y
                        }
                        return false
                    })

                    let groups = items.categorise {$0.dia!}

                    let sorted = groups.sorted(by: { (x, y) -> Bool in
                        return x.key < y.key
                    })
                    for xx in sorted {
                        if let componets = groups[xx.key] {
                            var strings = [String]()
                            for x in componets {
                                if let ss = x.jornada {
                                    strings.append(ss)
                                }
                            }
                            print("dia \(xx.key) jordano \(strings.joined(separator:" - "))")
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
        }
        catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I print the "dia"? for example 1 05:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 12:00:00 - 19:00:00